# Communicating between fragments within an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to write a test app which contains an activity. There are two fragments inside this activity, which are defined as `LeftFragment` and `RightFragment`. I used `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById()` to get connection from each other fragments. By using that methode I am able to get an `LeftFragment` object from `RightFragment`, but not `RightFragment` object from `LeftFragment`. It just works only oneway. I am doing this, because I want to call some operations from other fragment, that return some values. I was thinking about using EventBus but I failed too. How can I achive that?

Here is my `LeftFragment`

```
public class LeftFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        RightFragment rightFragment = (RightFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.rightFragment);
        if (rightFragment != null){
             makeToast(rightFragment.getMessageFromRight());
        }else {
            makeToast("does not found rightFragment");
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_left, container, false);
    }
    public String getMessageFromLeft(){
        return "Hi! Im left";
    }
    private void makeToast(String text){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And here is my `RightFragment`

```
    public class RightFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        LeftFragment leftFragment = (LeftFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.leftFragment);
        if (leftFragment != null){
            makeToast(leftFragment.getMessageFromLeft());
        }else {
            makeToast("does not found leftFragment");
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_right, container, false);
    }
    public String getMessageFromRight(){
        return "Hi! Im right!";
    }
    private void makeToast(String text){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is all explained in the documentation how to communicate between fragments: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably what is happening is that the Left Fragment is getting the OnCreateView() call first, at which point the Right Fragment has not been inflated yet (therefore it can't be "found" by findFragmentbyId()).

I would suggest moving the code that gets the references to the other fragments into onStart(), and only inflate the fragments in onCreateView().

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to communicate between 2 fragments . If 2 fragments loaded at the same time. I usaually use one of 2 ways below to do it.

1. You can use this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) using obserable pattern to communication 2 fragments.
2. you can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) lib for communication, it 's very simple

Your issue:

> By using that methode I am able to get an LeftFragment object from
>   RightFragment, but not RightFragment object from LeftFragment

I think your problem is `LeftFragment` is intitialized previous, so you can find it from `RightFragment`. Your solution is ok, using `EventBus`. YOu need to review  your codes to find the issue. You can test by creating other methods, after 2 fragment  was initialized.

For ex: click button in `LeftFragment`, toast a message in `RightFragment`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wanted to mark your answer as correct, but Joels answer was first and it solved my problem too. I will try to use eventbus anyway.

Comment: No problems. :)